# javascript : apply plugin at once to all vs one by one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, rendering, user-experience

I've home page. There is 5-6 dynamically generated jquery sliders inside the page. for ex.

```
<div id="slider1" class="slider">
    // images here 
</div>

<div id="slider2" class="slider">
    // images here 
</div>
.......
.......
```

The slider plugin is apply after all slider loaded at the end of the page as,

```
$('#slider1').applyplugin();
$('#slider2').applyplugin();
.....
.....
```

Now question is : Should the plugin applied to all sliders **at once** at the end of page; or should i apply sliders **one by one** as shown below,

```
<div id="slider1" class="slider">
...... images here .....
</div>
$('#slider1').applyplugin();

<div id="slider2" class="slider">
...... images here .....
</div>
$('#slider2').applyplugin();
```

which would be better for **better user experience** ? or is there any other solution for this ?

EDIT : By mistake i've wrote `id=slider1`, its `slider1, slider2 ...`

Comment: Please do some effort to post at least valid HTML markup, IDs must be unique. BTW, why don't use class selector?

Comment: Wait for dom to load and do it all at once! $('#slider1, #slider2').applyplugin();

Comment: @Alex Ya, or: `$('.slider').applyplugin();`

Comment: @A.Wolff even better!

Comment: No guys. i can't apply to all classes for some reason. I must have to apply it id by id.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't really explained what problem you're trying to solve with "better user experience"?  For example, are you  more concerned with all sliders showing at once?  With no slider showing before another slider?  With no HTML showing before the sliders have been initialized?  etc...

Assuming that `.applyplugin()` is properly written to handle more than one element at a time, you can simplify your javascript with:

```
$("#slider1, #slider2").applyplugin();
```

or use a common class name:

```
$(".slider").applyplugin();
```

Also, I'm assuming it's just a typo in your question as you can't have two elements with the same ID.

---

If you want to make sure that the elements aren't shown at all until they are properly initialized, you can do this:

```
<div id="slider1" class="slider" style="visibility: hidden;">
...... images here .....
</div>

<div id="slider2" class="slider" style="visibility: hidden;">
...... images here .....
</div>
$(".slider").css("visibility", "visible").applyplugin();
```

If this doesn't address the user experience you're trying to make better, please explain more about what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But  i can use neither single liner code to apply plugin nor with a class.

Comment: @user3710243 - why not?  The plugin method is poorly written if it can't handle more than one target element at a time.  What user experience problem are you actually trying to solve?